# How to add panMovement to UITableView Cell

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I have a table and custom cell from NIB. Basically what I need is to slide the custom cell from the table to the right side. It has to be smooth, and the table itself should not collapse. (The cell will get back after the action is done). I have some number of sections, and 1 row/section, so basically I need to move with the section. Thanks a lot for the answer!

My cell.m file looks like this:

```
#import "MIKETableViewCell.h"

static NSString *CellTableIdentifier = @"MIKETableViewCell";

@implementation MIKETableViewCell

@synthesize timeLabel = _timeLabel;
@synthesize priceLabel = _priceLabel;
@synthesize infoLabel = _infoLabel;


- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    // Initialization code
}

-(id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString*)reuseIdentifier {
self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:CellTableIdentifier];

return self;
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

// Configure the view for the selected state
}


@end
```

Comment: Have you tried anything already to achieve this?

Comment: I tried to put the panMovement action in IB to the cell. Same as I do on views in ViewControllers, but that did not work, and I tried some other solutions from tutorials, but nothing worked for me :/ I'm sure I'm missing some basic...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this:

```
 -(void)layoutSubviews
 {
     UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tableCellClicked)];
    tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
    [self addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];
 }
```

Comment: Could you please be more specific? Can you show it in my code? Thank You very much

Comment: Does -(id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString*)reuseIdentifier being called in your code?

Comment: Got it. 
Edited the answer for you

Comment: The action is initiated, when panning on the cell, but the cell is not moving. I added same movement method (code) as for subviews in other view, where it's working fine... Maybe different approach in tableView? Anyway this answered my question how to initiate action, thanks for that ;)

Comment: add another question with your code and I'll try to help
 cheers!

Comment: It could be that only one instance of the panGesture is being allocated and applied on only one of your cells, But the other cells do not have the gesture recogniser.